# Select names based on certian criteria and display in a second spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that is tracking weight loss for a group of people. I want to take the data from one spreadsheet (name, body fat loss %) and output to a second spreadsheet (name, body fat loss %) based on a static percentage. An example is if a group of people lose 1% body fat, they would be displayed in one group.

The Tracker Spreadsheet looks like

```
+---+------+--------+------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+----------+
|   |  A   |   B    |  C   |  D  |  E   |  F   |  G   |  H  |  I  |  J   |  K   |  L   |  M  |  N   |  O   |  P   |    Q     |
+---+------+--------+------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+----------+
| 1 | Name | Depart | 6/27 | 7/4 | 7/11 | 7/18 | 7/25 | 8/1 | 8/8 | 8/15 | 8/22 | 8/29 | 9/5 | 9/12 | 9/19 | 9/26 | % Change |
| 2 | Tom  | Bus    | 31   | 30  |      |      |      |     |     |      |      |      |     |      |      |      |     -1   |
| 3 | Jon  | Bus    | 32.5 | 32  |      |      |      |     |     |      |      |      |     |      |      |      |    -.5   |
+---+------+--------+------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+----------+
```

The grouping spreadsheet looks like

```
+----+------+--------+
|    |  A   |   B    |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | Name | % Lost |
|  2 | Tom  | 1      |
+----+------+--------+
```

I am unsure which function(s) to use to achive this.

Comment: I'd probably use `Power Query` and group by % lost.  You'll probably want to round that calculation, or use some other method so as to not have, for example, 1.15% lost and 1.17% lost in two different groups.

Comment: So which groups do you have? Just 1%? Depending on your excel licence you could get all names in one cell using `TEXTJOIN()` using the group % as criteria.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld my thought was to use a comparison operator to keep it in the 1% range.

Comment: @JvdV there are two other groups. 2% and 3%.

Comment: Like @RonRosenfeld mentioned, you better make sure that column Q croups these people under either 1, 2 or 3% lost. From there it is fairly easy to group all people. So their must be some rule of thumb from which % loss they fall in either group 1, 2 or 3

Comment: I'd probably use `ROUND` or `INT` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If understood correctly what you trying, then this could work:

[image]

You need some rule of thumb to say under which group people fall. Therefore the first thing I did was put formula in cell `Q2`

```
=ROUND(MIN(C2:O2)-C2,0)
```

And dragged down. Obviously if you want rounding to be different you must apply your own rule.

Next thing in `A9` I used formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($Q$2:$Q$5=B9,$A$2:$A$5,""))
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down.

Comment: I ended up using `=INT()`, that seemed to work nicely. However, i wasn't clear on the second table. I have three tables, table one is just for 1%er's, table two is for 2%er's .You get the point. Can `textjoin` still do the same thing?

Comment: Off course it can, just apply the same formula over the three tables, adjust their ranges to suit your needs.

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` throws a #NAME? error, so i tried just doing an IF, but that throws an error as well. `=TEXTJOIN("","",TRUE,IF(Table1[Tier]=1,Table1[Name],""))`

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Textjoin came out in 2016 I think.

Comment: MS Office Home and Business 2016. Version 1905. According to the MS Support Website TextJoin isn't in 2016.

Comment: Probably no license with TEXTJOIN enabled then. If you want to achieve the same thing, your best bet is an UDF, unless your output layout can also be different.

Comment: You were able to help me put the people into a group by adding another column and using INT. Moving forward i may have to just dump the grouping spreadsheet and using a table filter to pull names.

Comment: First you need to decide what your desired output needs to be. If it can be a list of names instead of grouped names in one cell, it can still be done using a formula. Glad I could help

Comment: Also, @JvdV, your rounded formula in only giving a number, not a percentage.

Comment: =ROUND((($C2-LOOKUP(2,1/($C2:$O2<>""),$C2:$O2))/$C2)*100,0)

Comment: @nathansutherland I assumed the numbers in OPs first table are representing percentages. If so, the formula is correct.

Comment: @nathansutherland, no worries. Why I thought so, the numbers don't reflect a % symbol. So most likely they just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This would put names in a table based on their % Lost

[image: % Table]

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,SMALL(IF($Q$2:$Q$5=-1,ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1),ROW()-ROW(A$8))),"")
```

Confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

This will give you the Change between the first and last day with data:

```
=ROUND((LOOKUP(2,1/($C2:$P2<>""),$C2:$P2)-$C2),0)
```

[image]